# get rows of data from jdbc ResultSet

Tags: java, mysql, sql, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to work with sqlite in Java using jdbc-sqlite. As I am not used to working with strongly typed languages, I expected to be able to make a SELECT query and the get the data returned in a list of rows.

It then occured to me that collections in java can only hold objects of the same type, so this is probably why it is not readily possible.

So how would I do this? Will I actually have to loop through all rows and then cast types in order to maintain polymorphism? Or will I need to harcode every single operation that uses data from a table/join? This seems to me absolutely insane.

So, in short: How can I retrieve my data as rows?

Comment: Read documentation @ [*Retrieving Values from Result Sets*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try Spring `JdbcTemplate.queryForList` it return `List<Map<String, Object>>`, map per row, map represents a column/value pairs